# How to get array data on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this Firebase:

[image: The code]

I'm trying to get all the questions data with this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference questionsRef = database.getReference("questions");

questionsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        HashMap question = dataSnapshot.getValue(HashMap.class);

        System.out.println(question.get("0"));
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class
>   java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use
>   GenericTypeIndicator instead

I tried few ways but this is last error. How I can get each question data and all the options of the questions?

Answer (score 1):

Options looks like a numbered list to me, so don't have to use a Map to get it's contents.

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> gti = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};

String question = dataSnapshot.child("question").getValue(String.class);
List<String> questionOptions = dataSnapshot.child("options").getValue(gti);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change `question` type to `Map`, not `HashMap` ([like @varjo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42384866/4112725))

Second, in your code you get the value is 1 step above where it should be. So it should be like this:

```
Map<String, String> question = dataSnapshot.child("options").getValue(Map.class);
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

To get question text, use this:

```
String questionText = dataSnapshot.child("question").getValue(String.class);
```

> Note: for best practice, I think you should create a custom object
>   that combine the question and options together

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> question = dataSnapshot.child("options").getValue(Map.class);
```

Take Array of this question..

Answer (score 0):

"options" is not a map, it is a list or an array. Do something like this

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
List<String> list = dataSnapshot.child("options").getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
```